# how to deploy database file in cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to mac app development. created an os x app which syncs data across network, the app has to store data inside the tables of a sqlite db file . info.db

When app is deployed db file with empty tables will be located inside the app for example

/Applications/myapp.app/somehere/info.db

Should the app on the first run move this info.db to some other data folder ? or temp directory, before it inserts data  ? or should I directly commit changes to the file inside the app bundle ? also when user updates the information from info.db stored by previous version will be used by newer version.  So, can you advise how this should be deployed ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the app bundle, so you must copy the empty database to a user directory upon first run.  If you are hoping to publish this app to the Mac App Store then it must be sandboxed which means that the only place you can put the database is in the app container folder.

You can obtain the app container folder using [`NSHomeDirectory()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory), which will work whether you sandbox the app or not.

Comment: Excellent for the clear cut answer. I am not currently deploying on mac app store, but may be in future. currently only to be installed via a .pkg installer. Guess I can make a subfolder in the user home directory for my app data.

Comment: As far as I know you can change files in the app file/container, but... it's not recommended, it will break app signing and you will get rejected is submitted to App Store.

Comment: @d00dle I think you are confusing the app container with the app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create a new directory in the User's Home folder. Apple has defined  "Standard" directories for various uses. In your case it sounds like you want Application Support.

Copy the empty database file to the Application Support directory. You can get a path/URL to Application Support from NSFileManager, like so:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                             inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
```

Then add your app's bundle ID to that path and create your own folder in Application Support.

There's sample code and a deeper explaination here on Apple's site:
[Locating Items in the Standard Directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW1)

Source